# How to ESlint a string on the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, eslint

I am building a in-browser IDE and am looking for a way to run ESlint on the JS code my users are writing. I am using react and the code that was written is stored in the state as a string. Is there any tool to just take that string and execute ESlint on it? I did not find anything.

If this is not available: Any ideas how to do what i want to do in the browser on the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, [ESLint doesn't support running in the browser](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8348), but [it is possible](https://eslint.org/demo/). When run on Node.js, ESLint reads built-in rules, plugins, and custom rules from the filesystem. For the demo, [a build step replaces the rule loader](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/f85547a961800ba568c9b52c90060b2006c00c84/Makefile.js#L822-L853) with static `require()` calls so that ESLint and its built-in rules can be combined into a single package for the browser. I'd suggest starting there. If you can get it loaded in the browser, then you can use the [`Linter` API](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/nodejs-api#linter) by passing it your string and a configuration object.